# What's the best shell script to monitor output of shell command and email me if it matches a string?

Tags: shell

I need a shell script to run in background on my Apple OS X (High Sierra) system, and every few minutes run the pmset command (to get status of power - UPS battery or outlet), and if it says that it's on a UPS (power failure) send me an email. It looks like this:

```
% pmset -g batt
Now drawing from 'AC Power'
 -OR1500PFCRT2U (id=1133707264) 111%; charging present: true
```

This is normal operation, so no email should be sent. This is what it shows when the outlet is off and the UPS is providing power:

```
% pmset -g batt
Now drawing from 'UPS Power'
 -OR1500PFCRT2U (id=1117585408) 119%; discharging; 0:52 remaining present: true
```

In this case, I'd like it to send me an email. What's the easiest way to have a shell script running in background to check this and email me?

Comment: A request for someone to give you some code, or point at code that was already written elsewhere, is off-topic here. By contrast, if you're trying to write a program *yourself*, ask a question about a specific problem you encountered in the process and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: (That said, if your question is just "how can I configure my UNIX system to notify me when it falls over to battery?", consider [unix.se]; note that you'll want to search for existing asked-and-answered instances before asking the question anew).

Comment: I'd probably use a `cron` job run every N minutes.  It would run a script; it would keep a record of how often it sent email so as not to overwhelm me with email.

Comment: use crontab and set the recurrence inside based on the time-need to trigger your script. inside the script configure your mail/mailx/sendmail command to send out emails.

Comment: Here is the issue I've run into, trying to write this: I am using the "sendmail" command in the syntax I've found on-line, 

% echo "hello" | sendmail -f me@mail.com -t me@mail.com

and it gives no error but also no email gets sent. Where can I see the error that it's presumably getting, and where do I set things like the smtp info (I'll use my gmail address) so that it can actually send?